# How do I import custom libraries in Databricks notebooks?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I uploaded a jar library on my cluster in Databricks [following this tutorial](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/workspace-libraries.html), however I have been unable to import the library or use the methods of the library from the Databricks notebook. I have been unable to find forums or documentation that address this topic, so I'm unsure if it's even possible at this point.

I am able to run the jar file as a job in Databricks, I just haven't been able to import the jar library into the Notebook to run it from there.

I also tried running the jar file using the %sh magic command but received the following `JNI error`:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
```

Comment: Update: running the jar using the %sh command didn't work as java code cannot be run in the Databricks notebook, hence the error. See: https://azurelib.com/how-to-run-java-code-on-azure-databricks/

Comment: you can refer for complete solution here . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543850/how-to-install-a-library-on-a-databricks-cluster-using-some-command-in-the-noteb

Answer (score 0):

This error generally caused because of Scala version. I would recommend upgrading Scala version and then try to import custom library.

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
> try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> scala/Function0

Refer - [Apache Spark Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050341/apache-spark-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-scala-co)